# How can I pull out a row in a GROUP BY Django query?

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models

I have a table like this:

```
EVENT
-------------
user_id   thumbnail_name
0         event/abc.jpg
0         event/efg.jpg
0         event/xyz.jpg
1         event/lmn.jpg
1         event/opq.jpg
2         event/rsf.jpg
```

How can I GROUP BY user_id and retrieve an arbitrary thumbnail? Expected output:

```
[ {user_id: 0, thumbnail_name: event/abc.jpg},
  {user_id: 1, thumbnail_name: event/lmn.jpg},
  {user_id: 2, thumbnail_name: event/rsf.jpg},
]
```

Is this even possible in SQL much less Django ORM?

Answer (score 1):

Use FOR JSON AUTO in SQl Server

```
SELECT *
FROM EVENT
FOR JSON AUTO
```

If you expect to return just a single row, then you can add Without_Array_Wrapper after FOR JSON AUTO with a comma after the AUTO keyword, and you will get an object instead of an array:

```
SELECT *
 FROM EVENT
 FOR JSON AUTO, Without_Array_Wrapper;
```

in MySQL

```
SELECT json_object('user_id', user_id, 'thumbnail_name', thumbnail_name)
FROM EVENT;
```

Fuhrer Modifications

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('user_id', user_id, 'thumbnail_name', thumbnail_name)) from EVENT;
```

Comment: This syntax did not compile in MySQL

Comment: @Rage updated with mysql version, let me know if this does not work

Comment: Your query now compiles, however it does not group by user_id